# Nuget install without version number in path

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

Is there a way to add -ExcludeVersion as default behaviour for nuget in VS 2015.

Comment: Given that you can either get latest or specify a version, I'm not sure why this would be required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-ExcludeVersion` option in NuGet command line used to excludes the version number from the installation folder, which is not a default action for nuget. This is why nuget will provide this option to let users exclude the version number manually.

There has another user has the same requirement, they have submit this requirement to NuGet, you could vote and add your comments in following link for this requirement.

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1522

Comment: Thanks but nuget have moved to GitHub and the thread is 2 years old. I just have to live with version numbers in my build files )-: